# How to filter out external playlists from Apple Music?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mpmedialibrary

I want to add track to the particular playlist using this method:

```
- (void)addItemWithProductID:(NSString *)productID completionHandler:(nullable void (^)(NSError * __nullable error))completionHandler;
```

Currently I am using this filter to filter playlists which would not generate error when adding item using productID/trackID. It filters valid playlists, but not all. After running this filter external playlist is not filtered out.

```
for (MPMediaPlaylist *playlist in [playlistsQuery collections]) {
    NSUInteger attribute = [[playlist valueForProperty:MPMediaPlaylistPropertyPlaylistAttributes] unsignedIntegerValue];
    if (!(attribute & MPMediaPlaylistAttributeSmart || attribute & MPMediaPlaylistAttributeGenius)) {
        [_playlists addObject:playlist];
    }
}
```

**How to filter out external playlists?**

Comment: I have noticed that adding a track to a newly created playlist does not always work. Is this your case ?

Comment: StoreId (from setQueueWithStoreIDs), productId (from addItemWithProductID), trackId and collectionId (from iTunes API) seem to be all the same. However, I'd like to know why/how their API naming review process let slip setQueueWithStoreIDs and addItemWithProductID.

Comment: @FKDev I did not notice this behavior.